# There are how many ways can we list, without repetition of all the elements of $S = \{ x, y, z\}$

Tags: combinatorics

Solution: there are six ways: $xyz$, $xzy$, $yxz$, $yzx$, $zxy$ and $zyx$.

Doubt: How do we know there are six possible ways?

Comment: You listed them all, and the numbers are small enough that it is clear you got them all, and did not inadvertently repeat any.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are free to choose any for the first so 3 options because nothing has thus far been chosen. Then 2 for the second because we can't use the one we had for the first. Then one option is remaining for the last entry in the permutation because we already used two of the options. so we have $3!=3*2*1=6$ in general the way to arrange $n$ things is $n!$ called n [Factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial)

---

$$\begin{array}{rcll} \swarrow&\downarrow&\searrow & \times 3
\\
x\underline{\;}\,\underline{\;}\quad & y\underline{\;}\,\underline{\;} & \quad z\underline{\;}\,\underline{\;}
\\  \swarrow\searrow\quad&  \swarrow\searrow& \quad\swarrow\searrow& \times 2
\\ xy\underline{\;}\quad xz\underline{\;} & yx\underline{\;} \quad yz\underline{\;}& zx\underline{\;}\quad  zy\underline{\;}
\\ \downarrow\qquad \downarrow\quad & \downarrow\qquad \downarrow& \quad\downarrow\qquad \downarrow & \times 1
\\ xyz \quad xzy\; & yxz\quad  yzx & \; zxy\quad zyx
\end{array}$$

Comment: can you elaborate  more on the fact that there are 3 options for the first, then 2 for the second and 1 option remaining . what do you meant by that?

Comment: @NemanNasawa You can select either one of $x,y,$ or $z$ for the first place.  Whichever you select, there are two remaining choices for the second place. Then the third place can only be filled by the one remaining element.  By the principle of counting: there are $3\times 2\times 1$ distinct ways to do this in total.